# where name has duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

databaseHey guys I need some help with some SQL syntax what I'm trying to do is have the query only show records where there is more than one first name so it'll show customer bob if he has two records but ignore Jill because she has only one record

```
`SELECT [SubID]
      ,[Title]
      ,[FName]
      ,[LName]
      ,[State]
      ,[Zip]
      ,[DOB]
      ,[DriverLicence]
      ,[Cell_Number]
      ,[Account_Number]
      ,[Email_Address]
      ,[CreatedDate]
  FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
  WHERE [Zip] = '0000' OR [zip] = '0001' OR [zip] = '0002'AND IF COUNT(Fname)=>1
  ORDER BY [CreatedDate]`
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you working with?  SQL Server?

Comment: @EricJ. of course not, `COUNT()` is aggregate function and have to use only in `select` and `having` statements. And it is not only in SQL Server it is SQL rule

Comment: yes its SQL Sever and no its not valid which is my problem also being a newb at SQL is my other problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `group by` and `having`.

```
select [SubID]
  ,[Title]
  ,t.[FName]
  ,[LName]
  ,[State]
  ,[Zip]
  ,[DOB]
  ,[DriverLicence]
  ,[Cell_Number]
  ,[Account_Number]
  ,[Email_Address]
  ,[CreatedDate]
 FROM [HSEnroll_PI].[dbo].[Enrollment_PI] t
 JOIN (
 select fname
 from [HSEnroll_PI].[dbo].[Enrollment_PI]
 group by fname
 having count(*) > 1 ) x
 on x.fname = t.fname
 WHERE [Zip] = '0000' OR [zip] = '0001' OR [zip] = '0002'
 order by createddate
```

Comment: using this syntax resulted in no results appearing

Comment: the query has been modified.try the most latest one. also, do you get results for the inner query run alone?

Comment: ran it again the join appears to ignore my where statement and it almost crashed my database ha ha

Comment: changed the `where` clause to be in the final query. try this.

Comment: that works perfectly Im just having trouble getting a does not equal to work  i want to exclude a specific string from [Lname] field i tried to do
and [LName] <> 'String'

Answer (score 0):

Group By works and Having works, but I like the ROW_NUMBER approach better and cleaner:

```
WITH a as
(
SELECT [SubID]
      ,[Title]
      ,[FName]
      ,[LName]
      ,[State]
      ,[Zip]
      ,[DOB]
      ,[DriverLicence]
      ,[Cell_Number]
      ,[Account_Number]
      ,[Email_Address]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by FName ORDER BY FName) AS duplicateRecCount
  FROM [HSEnroll_PI].[dbo].[Enrollment_PI]
  WHERE [Zip] = '0000' OR [zip] = '0001' OR [zip] = '0002'
)
SELECT * FROM a
where duplicateRecCount > 1
```

Comment: thank you works perfectly with row_number outputs each duplicate as a single line is it possible to have it show ALL the duplicates instead of one line per duplicate?